# Access Sharepoint List on another ASP Application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

Is is possible to access a sharepoint list into my asp application which is to be deployed on another server? If yes, please share your thoughts.

I have tried using rss reader (jquery plugin) and xml reader of asp but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is to access the SharePoint list using a service account that has administrative permission on the list.